# How operating system obtain process switching

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, scheduler

How operating system obtain process switching. I would like speak about it more general. We are in multitasking age, I know basic concept that there is some scheduler which authoritatively point which process will now run. My question is more **how processor guarantee that some process will consume X time and then next process will be executed**. Is there any low-level mechanism which **break process** after some specific time? Or it's some kind of abstract method to achieve that?

Is it possible to implement something what break current task and switch execution to another without special processor help? If no, **what do we need to implement it**. Let's assume I would like to implement something like this in some simple uC like Atmega8 (it's just example of uC, we could use other, from other family)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods (that I can think of off the top of my head) that can cause a context switch:

1) The process/thread yields. This tends to be the most frequent cause of context switches. The thread queues and I/O request and waits for a response. The wait causes the thread/process to yield.

2) Timer, as described above. In the case of a compute-bound process (all processing, no I/O, no page faults),  The CPU timer generates interrupts that the get handled in kernel mode. An operating system will have a set of house keeping task to perform on a timer interrupt. One of these will be to see if the current process has exceeded its quantum. If so, and there is another process ready at a higher priority, do a context switch.

Comment: 3) The I/O operation requeted in (1) completes, and the waiting thread is made running, preempting another thread.

Comment: The timer interrupt will be unable to find a ready  process/thread with a higher priority - any such thread would have been set running 'immediately' when it became ready, preempting the thread of lower priority.

Answer (score 0):

Google for 'interrupts'.  With modern preemptive kernels, syscalls from running threads/processes, and hardware interrupts that cause drivers to run, are the events that can drive the OS kernel scheduling state-machine and hence the set of processes/threads that will run next on the cores available.

On many OS designs, especially on limited hardware, there is no such thing as 'processor guarantee that some process will consume X time'.  Others have anti-starvation algorithms built-in to the scheduler.

There are other scheduling algorithms that seek to supply guarantees, but this is very difficult in the face of conflicting demands from syscalls and hardware-interrupts upon I/O completion events

Comment: Or query `Wikipedia` for 'interrupts' or [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)